# neo4j single node maximum relationship capacity

Tags: neo4j

searched, and read from [capacity](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/capabilities-capacity.html) documents, but I can't get figures on what is the maximum capacity for a single node to have?

If I have a user, that has so many posts, comments, uploads, etc, that is related to him, is there any maximum of relations that I can attach to him?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not really a maximum / limit.

The relationships are stored in separate structures by type and direction.

For some use-cases it might make sense to separate some information out to a separate node, it depends on the use-cases that you want to support with your graph model.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense to me now.